# Conversion and Manipulation of an IPAddress of type NSString to NSInteger

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, nsstring

I have a network application I'm working on. 
What I want to do is to be able to add and subtract numbers to specific IPv4 Address Octets.

Example. Say if the device's current IPAddress is: 10.43.223.71
But I want to add 40 onto the 2nd octet which would make it 10.83 and put a new string .210 onto the last octet. Making the newly constructed IPAddress 10.83.223.210

Now, I know I can use NSString to get the IPAddress (Which I already have). I can then use NSMutableArray of type NSString then use the componentsSeperatedByString "." to split each octet apart. This part I have done already.

This is where I'm a little hazy on what I should do next. Should now initiate a conversion from NSString to NSInteger? Should I save/and how would I save each octet temporarily so I can re-add specific octets later on.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create an `IPv4` class? This class would internally have 4 integer values. You can create instances of this class from an `NSString` (as an IP address) as well as 4 integers.

This class should have methods for setting/getting any of the 4 numbers as well as getting the string representation.

With all of this basic logic properly encapsulated in a nice little class, your code for using this becomes much simpler.

Comment: I really appreciate your quick response. I'm not opposed to creating a custom class to utilize that to keep code simple and clean. I guess my biggest concern/question is that with the 2nd octet, the 2nd octet is a numerical value that should be added...but it's country dependent. So US would have +40, Canada would have +100, etc..

For the last octet, the last octet would be provided by a remote JSON file. I already have that NSJSONSerialization built in, and that works swell. It's manipulating that 2nd octet I'm stuck on. How would you go about structuring the IPv4 class and implementation.

Comment: This "IPv4" class wouldn't have any of those details. It would simply split the string into four integers and have methods that let you get and set each of the 4 values. That's it. So you create an instance with a string such as "10.43.223.71". Then if you want to add 40 to the 2nd octet, you would ask the instance for the 2nd value (and get 43). You would add 40 to it. Then you would pass the new value for the 2nd octet to the instance.

Comment: I see what you're saying!! That's a grand idea! That makes sense, and is quite simple yet elegant. I appreciate your feedback very much!